# Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown links don't work on small screens <576px

Tags: javascript, navbar, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I'm new to this.  I have a working navbar with dropdown that has 3 links.  After expansion, the dropdown links display a card upon clicking (cards show contact info), and all works fine...except for when I go to mobile view below <576px.

I've used a template with CDNs directly from Boostrap for CSS, Javascript bundle, and Icons.

Why does this work, but it becomes not responsive once below <576px ????

Soon as I go greater than >576px it works again.  This is driving me nuts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Bootstrap Icons CDN -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />
    <style>
      .bg-dark-transparent {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
    </style>
    <title>Bio Website</title>
  </head>
  <body class="vh-100 bg-dark text-light">
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="badge bg-danger shadow">Joe Noobie</span></a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarMain"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMain">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" style="z-index: 10">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                href=""
                class="nav-link active"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target=".multi-collapse"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="about contact"
                >Info</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                href="#about"
                role="button"
                class="nav-link"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="about"
                >About</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                href="#contact"
                role="button"
                class="nav-link"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="contact"
                >Contact</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <header class="container fixed-top text-end mt-5">
      <!-- HEADER > About & Contact dropdown content -->
      <div class="row mt-3">
        <!-- About  -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
          <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="about">
            <div class="card card-body text-start shadow bg-dark-transparent">
              <h5 class="card-title text-danger">About</h5>
              <div class="card-text">
                <h3 class="text-white-50 ms-3">Joe Noobie</h3>
                <ul class="list-unstyled ms-5">
                  <li>CEO of Noobie Media</li>
                  <li>Web Developer</li>
                  <li>Tech Support</li>
                  <li>Graphic Designer</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Contact -->
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
          <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="contact">
            <div class="card card-body text-start shadow bg-dark-transparent">
              <h5 class="card-title text-danger">Contact</h5>
              <div class="card-text">
                <h3 class="text-white-50 ms-3">Get in touch:</h3>
                <ul class="list-unstyled ms-5">
                  <li><i class="bi bi-house me-2 text-danger"></i>City: The City</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-signpost me-2 text-danger"></i>Street: 21 Jump Str.</li>
                  <li><i class="bi bi-telephone me-2 text-danger"></i>Phone: +555-555-555</li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="bi bi-envelope me-2 text-danger"></i>Email: JoeNoobie@Noobalicious.com
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove the "fixed-top" class from nav and header tags**, removing this class makes the tags rendered one-after the other in the default "static" positioning way.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">

 <header class="container text-end mt-5">
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I did not upload my question with the content that needed to have the fixed-top class.  I ended up keeping the fixed-top class in the nav tag and it worked like a charm!  Once again....THANK YOU!  : )

Comment: Sorry, Could not understand what you are saying, Hope my answer solves your problem, If not kindly share the your question here I will try my best

Comment: Your answer was correct and spot on.  What I meant was, that I removed the fixed-top class only from the header tag.  I left the fixed-top class in the nav tag....I needed that for my design that was not pictured on my original post.  Thanks again...you got the problem solved!